# NetDisturb using Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am trying to develop a script in Python which would function like the NetDisturb utility. Some of you might ask why am I doing this if there is a ready made utility, but the thing is I want to integrate this in a web page. Using this web page I can access a particular set of interfaces which I already know or are present in the back end script and eventually degrade the performance or simply block packets.

I have succeeded a little but now I want to implement a socket connection between the two interfaces which would be connected. I am unable to have a full duplex communication using a socket connection. I am unable to decide which interface should act as master and which interface should act as slave. Because when I make one of the interface as master the `listen` and `accept` statements block further execution of the code.

Would using `SOCK_DGRAM` sockets instead of `SOCK_STREAM` help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use non-blocking sockets. [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#non-blocking-sockets)  is an explanation how to use `select` to handle non-blocking sockets (for beginners I could really recommend the complete article, it is a good start). Alternatives would be a multi-threaded architecture or [`asynchore`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html). If you want additionally a GUI, I can recommend `pygtk` for the interface and `glib.io_add_watch` to handle the sockets.

But in general I would recommend some high level framework like [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/). A second high level alternative would be Twisted, but it has a non-pythonic Java-like API and is (IMO) badly documented.